# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment

Tags: postgresql, jvm-crash

Ran into this JVM error after running an process for an extended period of time that reads records from a csv file, validates the data, and stores in in a database.  Using Hibernate and PostgreSQL.  The JVM dump mentions some psql classes.  Can anyone help with this?

Additional noteworthy infomation:
The process slows down over time but keeps a consistent CPU and memorry usage (about 150% CPU and 11.5% memory)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000073f4027bb, pid=977, tid=1111066944
#
# JRE version: 6.0_26-b03
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (20.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000073f4027bb
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000537bd000):  GCTaskThread [stack: 0x0000000042298000,0x0000000042399000] [id=985]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x0000000000000003, RDX=0x0000000740c37298
RSP=0x0000000042397b38, RBP=0x0000000042397bb0, RSI=0x00000007f65092b8, RDI=0x0000000740c372a8
R8 =0x0000000000000012, R9 =0x0000000000000012, R10=0x00000007f6fdafb9, R11=0x00002aaaaf38bf10
R12=0x00000007f65092b8, R13=0x0000000000000005, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000740c30ac0
RIP=0x000000073f4027bb, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010286, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000006
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000042397b38)
0x0000000042397b38:   00002b776b7c8dea 168cf3000000aacb
0x0000000042397b48:   00002b776baf73d0 168cf3000000aacc
0x0000000042397b58:   0000000053802720 0000000053802720
0x0000000042397b68:   0000000000000009 168cf3000000aacc
0x0000000042397b78:   00000007f6fdb02d 0000000042397ba0
0x0000000042397b88:   00000007f6fdafb8 00002b776bb09ee0
0x0000000042397b98:   00000000538027a0 0000000000000000
0x0000000042397ba8:   0000000000000001 0000000042397bd0
0x0000000042397bb8:   00002b776b7c914d 0000000053802720
0x0000000042397bc8:   0000000053802788 0000000042397c10
0x0000000042397bd8:   00002b776b7c85bf 00000007f6fdafb9
0x0000000042397be8:   0000000053802720 0000000000000006
0x0000000042397bf8:   00002aaab4cfe410 00002b776bb04f20
0x0000000042397c08:   0000000042397c2c 0000000042397c60
0x0000000042397c18:   00002b776b7cb948 0000000042397c30
0x0000000042397c28:   2ec7c4dd6b4cdc27 00000007f60b61ba
0x0000000042397c38:   00002b776baedc24 00002aaab4cfe410
0x0000000042397c48:   00000000537bd000 00002b776b937aa6
0x0000000042397c58:   0000000000000000 0000000042397d60
0x0000000042397c68:   00002b776b4ceefa 0000000042397cb0
0x0000000042397c78:   0000000042397c88 00002b776bb08ac0
0x0000000042397c88:   0000000000000000 00000000537bd4d0
0x0000000042397c98:   00000000537bd500 00000000537bd510
0x0000000042397ca8:   00000000537bd8e8 00000000537bd000
0x0000000042397cb8:   00000000537bd8f0 00000000537bd920
0x0000000042397cc8:   00000000537bd930 00000000537bdd08
0x0000000042397cd8:   0000000042397d00 00000000537bd4d0
0x0000000042397ce8:   00000000537bd500 00000000537bd510
0x0000000042397cf8:   00000000537bd8e8 00000000537bd000
0x0000000042397d08:   00000000537bd8f0 00000000537bd920
0x0000000042397d18:   00000000537bd930 00000000537bdd08
0x0000000042397d28:   00000000537bdd10 00000000537be630 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000073f4027bb)
0x000000073f40279b:   e7 00 00 00 00 14 00 6a 61 76 61 2f 75 74 69 6c
0x000000073f4027ab:   2f 50 72 6f 70 65 72 74 69 65 73 00 00 01 72 99
0x000000073f4027bb:   4a 0f 00 00 00 78 00 e8 e7 00 00 00 00 10 00 6a
0x000000073f4027cb:   61 76 61 2f 75 74 69 6c 2f 56 65 63 74 6f 72 00 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000000003 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000740c37298 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
RSP=0x0000000042397b38 is an unknown value
RBP=0x0000000042397bb0 is an unknown value
RSI=0x00000007f65092b8 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000740c372a8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R8 =0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000012 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000007f6fdafb9 is an unknown value
R11=0x00002aaaaf38bf10 is an unknown value
R12=0x00000007f65092b8 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000005 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000740c30ac0 is an oop
{constant pool} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - cache: 0x0000000740c4f550
 -   1 :  : klass_index=110 name_and_type_index=300
 -   2 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=301
 -   3 :  : klass_index=110 name_and_type_index=302
 -   4 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=303
 -   5 :  : klass_index=304 name_and_type_index=305
 -   6 :  : klass_index=306 name_and_type_index=307
 -   7 :  : klass_index=304 name_and_type_index=308
 -   8 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=309
 -   9 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=310
 -  10 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=311
 -  11 :  : 'org/postgresql/core/Field'
 -  12 :  : 'java/util/Vector'
 -  13 :  : klass_index=12 name_and_type_index=314
 -  14 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=315
 -  15 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=316
 -  16 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=317
 -  17 :  : 'java/lang/String'
 -  18 :  : "*" {0x73f6b2b18}
 -  19 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=320
 -  20 :  : klass_index=109 name_and_type_index=321
 -  21 :  : "8.2" {0x740a78928}
 -  22 :  : klass_index=323 name_and_type_index=324
 -  23 :  : 'org/postgresql/util/PSQLException'
 -  24 :  :
```

Comment: Got a very similar error. Did you find what caused it?

Answer (score 1):

The last time something like that happened to me, I found that the main memory on my computer was damaged, I know, I know, most likely everything's ok, but if I were you, i will check it out with memtest86+